# Physical meaning of the separation constants in Laplace's Equation for Electrostatics

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

In Electrostatics, if we consider a region without charges the electrostatic potential $V$ obeys Laplace's Equation $\nabla^2 V = 0$. We can tackle this with separation of variables. In cartesian coordinates we have $V(x,y,z) = X(x)Y(y)Z(z)$ and so the equation is:

$$\nabla^2 V = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \dfrac{X''(x)}{X(x)}+\dfrac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)}+\dfrac{Z''(z)}{Z(z)} = 0.$$

For this to happen there should be three constants $C_1,C_2,C_3$ such that

$$\begin{cases}X''(x) &= C_1 X(x), \\ Y''(y) &= C_2 Y(y), \\ Z''(z) &= C_3Z(z).\end{cases}$$

Now, another example of a problem in Physics tackled with separation of variables is Schrödinger's equation

$$i\hbar \dfrac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t} = H\Psi,$$

separation of variables yields two equations one of which is $H\psi = E\psi$ for the spatial part and the separation constant has one physical meaning as expected value of energy.

Now, the constants $C_1,C_2,C_3$ appearing when we separate variables on Laplace's equation for electrostatic potential has some physical meaning? If they do, what is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now, the constants C1,C2,C3 appearing when we separate variables on
>   Laplace's equation for electrostatic potential has some physical
>   meaning? If they do, what is it?

The constants are the related to the square of the spatial (angular) frequency or a spatial growth/decay constant.

For an example of spatial frequency, let

$$X(x) = A \sin (k_xx) + B \cos(k_xx)$$

Then

$$X''(x) = -k^2_x X(x)$$

Or, for an example of a spatial growth/decay constant, let

$$Y(y) = A e^{k_yy} + B e^{-k_yy}$$

Then

$$Y''(y) = k^2_y Y(y)$$